# Polymorphic smart pointer usage

Tags: c++, c++11

Until now I have had a function that was getting an argument of type `IArg` and I could do the following:

```
struct IArg
{
};

struct Arg : IArg
{
};

void f (IArg* arg)
{
// do something
}

f(new Arg);
```

Now when I got this:

```
void f (std::shared_ptr<IArg> arg)
{
// do something
}
```

Why it works again with

```
f(std::make_shared<Arg>());
```

`std::shared_ptr<A>` and `std::shared_ptr<B>` are different types even if `A` and `B` are related, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `std::shared_ptr<T>` is implicitly constructible from a `std::shared_ptr<U>` if and only if a `U *` is implicitly convertible to a `T *`.  See the constructor overload [(9) on `cppreference.com`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr).

Comment: Hope the check is not runtime.

Comment: @Narek Of course not. You can tell that by the phrase *“This overload doesn't participate in overload resolution if…”*. Overload resolution is a purely compile-time thing. An implementation would use SFINAE on that constructor to enable it if appropriate.

Comment: didn't get you, sorry

Comment: I'm not sure what is unclear but you can rest assured that there is no run-time check involved. Still note that the conversion is not free. You'll pay for every copy of a `std::shared_ptr` you make.

Answer (score 7):

It works because `std::shared_ptr` has a tempalted constructor which works when there is an implicit conversion from source pointer type to target pointer type.