# std::static_pointer_cast vs static_cast<std::shared_ptr<A>>

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class hierarchy and in it `B` is derived from `A` like this:

```
class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{

};

class B : public A
{
   void f()
   {
        // the code below compiles
        std::shared_ptr<B> copyOfThis = std::static_pointer_cast<B>(shared_from_this()); 
        // the code below does not
        std::shared_ptr<B> copyOfThis = static_cast<std::shared_ptr<B>>(std::make_shared<A>(shared_from_this()));
}
};
```

So actually I want to understand why I cannot use `static_cast`to cast a `shared_ptr` of parent class to child class when it is actually contains `this` of child.

EDIT: Look at this question: [Polymorphic smart pointer usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33632549/polymorphic-smart-pointer-usage) Here I have asked why shared pointer of child can be casted on shared pointer of parent. And the answer is there is a template constructor. See details in the question. So why this constructor does not help for casting even if there is no relationship between `shared_ptr<A>` and `shared_ptr<B>`.

Comment: What is `ActionLink` and `ILink`?

Comment: Sorry. Was real code. Now fixed!

Comment: What's your question, exactly? The two lines you showed attempt to do completely different things. The second allocates a new object, while the first only creates a shared pointer to the current object.

Comment: @interjay but that another object again points on `this` and my point is make another shared pointer that shows on `this`.

Comment: `std::make_shared` allocates a new managed object, different from `*this`.

Comment: What is `std::make_shared<A>(shared_from_this())` supposed to do? Have you tried compiling this code? That might answer your question.

Comment: @JonathanWakely it compiles just on Xcode.

Comment: @Narek, No it doesn't! `shared_from_this()` returns `shared_ptr<A>` and `A` has no constructor that takes `shared_ptr<A>`. Whatever you think compiles with Xcode is **not** the code you've shown above.

Comment: *“So why this constructor does not help?”* – Because you're now going the other way round. A `B *` is implicitly convertible to an `A *` but an `A *` does not convert implicitly to a `B *`. So the constructor does not participate in overload resolution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't cast `shared_ptr<A>` to `shared_ptr<B>` because there is no inheritance relationship between the types. For the same reason you can't cast `vector<A>` to `vector<B>`.

Instantiating a class template with related types does not make the template instantiations also related.

The `shared_ptr<T>(const shared_ptr<Y>&)` constructor doesn't help because it is only usable if `Y*` is implicitly convertible to `T*`, i.e. it is there to support the same pointer conversions as would happen implicitly, like `B*` to `A*`, *not* `A*` to `B*`.

What you *can* do is this:

```
shared_ptr<A> thisA = shared_from_this();
shared_ptr<B> thisB(thisA, static_cast<B*>(thisA.get()));
```

This creates a `shared_ptr<B>` that *shares ownership* with `thisA`, and holds the pointer `static_cast<B*>(thisA.get())`

That is exactly what `static_pointer_cast<B>(thisA)` does, but the aliasing constructor used above was added to `shared_ptr` later, so didn't exist when `static_pointer_cast` was invented, and it is also much less clear what it is doing. `static_pointer_cast` is much more expressive. If you want to perform a static cast on the pointer types, use `static_pointer_cast`.

Comment: Have you looked at my `EDIT` of my question?

Comment: The only way to static_cast between objects of classes having no relationship with each other, is the use of conversion operators.

Comment: @Narek, yes, see the updated answer, and read the docs of the constructor you're asking about! And read the answer to your other question!

Comment: So the only reason is upcasting, if I got you right.

Comment: @MarkusAtCvlabDotDe conversion operators and CTORs too.

Answer (score 8):

Long story short: `std::shared_ptr<A>` is **not** a parent of `std::shared_ptr<B>`. That is the whole point of `static_pointer_cast` existence.

Comment: @AnkitAcharya. He is not talking about the class A and B, but about the the two different generic classes std::shared_ptr<A> and std::shared_ptr<B>, which are indeed totally different classes.